How can you paste multiple selections in sublime text at the same indent level?
if i paste multiple copied selections, only the first entry is pasted at that indent level and the rest are pasted onto new lines with no indents.
how can i paste each copied selection from one caret position to the same indent level?
work around i have to go back and manually select then indent to the current level each time.
current result when pasting 3 copied selections from one caret position:
existing text
    indented existing text
    pasted text item 1
pasted text item 2
pasted text item 3

desired result
existing text
    indented existing text
    pasted text item 1
    pasted text item 2
    pasted text item 3

